# Exclude datetime from GroupBy sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm looking a way to use groupby on a dataframe that contains datetime64 format on some columns. But im having this error:

```
    dfsum = df.groupby(['City']).sum()
TypeError: datetime64 type does not support sum operations
```

I tried using:

```
desired = df.select_dtypes(include=[int, float, object])
dfsum_city = desired.groupby(['City']).sum()
dfsum_city.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

But i dont think it is the right way to solve the problem. Any advice?

| Order ID | Product | Quantity Ordered | Price Each | Order Date | Purchase Address | day | month | year | Total Price | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 141234 | iPhone | 1 | 700 | 2019-01-22 21:25:00 | 944 Walnut St, Boston, MA 02215 | 22 | 1 | 2019 | 700 | Boston (MA) |
| 141235 | Lightning Charging Cable | 1 | 14.95 | 2019-01-28 14:15:00 | 185 Maple St, Portland, OR 97035 | 28 | 1 | 2019 | 14.95 | Portland (OR) |
| 141236 | Wired Headphones | 2 | 11.99 | 2019-01-17 13:33:00 | 538 Adams St, San Francisco, CA 94016 | 17 | 1 | 2019 | 23.98 | San Francisco (CA) |
| 141237 | 27in FHD Monitor | 1 | 149.99 | 2019-01-05 20:33:00 | 738 10th St, Los Angeles, CA 90001 | 5 | 1 | 2019 | 149.99 | Los Angeles (CA) |
| 141238 | Wired Headphones | 1 | 11.99 | 2019-01-25 11:59:00 | 387 10th St, Austin, TX 73301 | 25 | 1 | 2019 | 11.99 | Austin (TX) |

Comment: can you give a sample of the dataset to run the code against.  your code looks good

Comment: @GoldenLion Just added a table. My code works, but i think this is not the right way to solve the problem.

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: @not_speshal I'm using pandas 2.1.0

Comment: what are you summing? it will sum all the numeric fields.  did you parse the order date and set it as a index. dfsum = df.groupby(['City'])['Price Each'].sum()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) has a `numeric_only` parameter you could switch to `True`, but in this case, I think you want to select specific columns, since summing the Order ID and day, month, and year doesn't make a lot of sense.

```
df.groupby(['City'])[['Quantity Ordered', 'Price Each', 'Total Price']].sum()
```

```
                    Quantity Ordered  Price Each  Total Price
City                                                         
Austin (TX)                        1       11.99        11.99
Boston (MA)                        1      700.00       700.00
Los Angeles (CA)                   1      149.99       149.99
Portland (OR)                      1       14.95        14.95
San Francisco (CA)                 2       11.99        23.98
```

Comment: This way looks more efficient, and cleaner, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try getting all the numerical columns to a `list` and then use `groupby` on those specific columns:

```
desired = df.select_dtypes(['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']).columns
output = df.groupby("City")[desired].sum()
```

Comment: This works like the answer i already tried, im asking if there is a better way to do it because this way i'm creating an "extra" dataframe that consumes resources